# Constraint prolog, creating optimization method

Tags: prolog, clpfd

so I have been around this problem for some time...
I want to solve this problem of optimization in Prolog using clpfd library:
Imagine a company has several measures they want to implement, and each measure has an impact to some criteria and a cost defined. The company has a limit buget.
For example a list of measures: (5 criteria for every measure)
[[id, cost, [list of impact on each criteria(1,2,3,4,5) from 0-100], average Impact], ... ]

```
measure(1, 100, [50,50,50,60,50]).
```

This is an example, i create a List of List of measure with the average impact...

The thing  i need is a method which will check if i can join measures with total Cost below budget and will look for the best set of measures to improve the Impact on all criteria.

Below is the code and example of a small db:

```
measure(1, 100, [100,90,100,100,100]).
measure(2, 10, [50,70,80,80,80]).
measure(3, 200, [50,50,50,100,20]).
measure(4, 80, [100, 100,100,100,100]).
```

The input would be :

```
strategy([0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2],190).
```

And the solution that i want to get is: Measures[4]. Because the average of impact is higher and Cost is below Budget. But i keep getting the first solution

```
strategy(Priorities, Budget):-
sumlist(Priorities, 1.0),
length(Priorities, 5),

setof([Id, Cost, Criteria], measure(Id, Cost, Criteria), List),
length(List, MaxLength),

%List of usable measures (Cost < Budget)
setof([Id, Cost, Criteria, Impact], (measure(Id, Cost, Criteria), Cost < Budget, sum_prod(Criteria, Priorities, Impact)), MeasuresList),
TotalImpact in 0 .. 100,

Length in 1 .. MaxLength,
length(Measures, Length),
domain(Measures, 1, MaxLength),
all_different(Measures),
write('Length: '), write(Length), nl,

checkMeasures(Measures, MeasuresList, Budget, TotalImpact),
labeling(maximize(TotalImpact), Measures),
write('TotalImpact: '), write(TotalImpact), nl,
write('Measures: '), write(Measures).

checkMeasures(Measures, MeasuresList, Budget, TotalImpact) :-
    measuresClause(Measures, MeasuresList, 0, Budget, 0, TotalImpact).

measuresClause([Id|Rest], MeasuresList, TotalSpent,
                Budget, ImpactSum, TotalImpact):-
    ImpactSum == 0,
    member([Id, Cost, _, Impact], MeasuresList),
    I is round(Impact),
    Aux #= I + ImpactSum,
    Sum #= Aux,
    TotalBudget #= Cost + TotalSpent,
    measuresClause(Rest, MeasuresList, TotalBudget, Budget, Sum, TotalImpact).
measuresClause([Id|Rest], MeasuresList, TotalSpent,
                Budget, ImpactSum, TotalImpact) :-
    member([Id, Cost, _, Impact], MeasuresList),
    I is round(Impact),
    Aux #= I + ImpactSum,
    Sum #= Aux/2,
    TotalBudget #= Cost + TotalSpent,
    measuresClause(Rest, MeasuresList, TotalBudget, Budget, Sum, TotalImpact).
measuresClause([], _, TotalSpent, Budget, ImpactSum, TotalImpact) :-
    TotalSpent #=< Budget,
    TotalImpact #= ImpactSum.
```

I have tried doing this:

```
    labeling([max(TotalImpact),time_out(30000,_), all], Measures),
```

But I just get the first available result

Comment: Can you provide some more input data to test the program?

Comment: Yes of course.
 i have this small db:
measure(1, 100, [50,50,50,60,50]).
measure(2, 10, [50,50,50,50,50]).
measure(3, 200, [50,50,50,100,20]).
measure(4, 80, [100, 100,100,100,100]).

And i added the code that was missing in the post.

So with this input: strategy([0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2],190).

I would like to get like Measures = [1,4], because Cost of 1 + Cost of 4 < Budget(the 190 of the input) but i only get Measures = [1].

Comment: I am sorry @damianodamiano for now the outcome i want is really the Measures = [4], because atm i am not entering with the Cost of each measure to evaluate the solution. Check the post because i edited it :)

Comment: @damianodamiano with this:
  solve([maximize(TotalImpact),time_out(30000,_),all], labeling(Measures))
 I get the method CheckMeasures to check all possible measures but doesnt return me anything...after checking measures with length 4, doesn't return me anything, just gets stucked. Any way you can help? Or know what is happening?

Comment: I suggest you to create a list of all available measures (in this case 4) and constraint the domain of each variable to be `0` or `1`. Then create some predicates (for example `constraintBudget`) and use reification predicates as  `#<==>`.